# JQM multipage app with one central JS and opening PDF (doc,..) PROBLEMS

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My apps structure is like so:

index.html / app. entry point includes in the `<head>...</head>` one central JS where i do custom scripting depending on which page is open and which event is triggered:
Here's a quick example for a page called mylist.html, and instead of having on every page it's scripting i have rather one larger JS which requires only one time to load in the `<head>` of index:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#pageMyList', function()        
{
     // init code   
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '#pageMyList', function()
{   
    // run every time
});
```

Shutting of JQM ajax and stuff is not an option since i need those transitions and go jqm "native".

PROBLEM:

I have a list of pdf's, doc's, external links,..etc that are all handled by browser. For example: opening pdf i just link to it (window.location = 'pathToPdfFile';

That works, but then the pdf reader is openened (iphone etc..). Now going back will open the last page but the index.html page isn't in the DOM anymore - and my entire JS not  available.

Btw: Pages are dynamically build via ajax.
The same happenz when i refresh any page (index.html) is lost

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually wanting to happen/accomplish? Are you just wanting the JS file to stay in the cache? in the DOM? or...?

Comment: Well, i forgot to mention but when i open a link that point's out to a file (pdf), the browser acts as a reader right and opens the pdf. So now i only have the browsers back button to go back to my app. Than the last page is opened but the first page (index.html) is lost from the DOM. And because index.html included my custom scripting JS file, i just got a blank page on returning from that PDF (DOC, XLS, EXTERNAL LINK, BROWSERS REFRESH BUTTON)... Question is: How do you JQM dev's handle this problem? (i thought that index.html was by default dom cache enabled) thx

Comment: See my answer... let me know if that's what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specifically tell JQM which pages to load into the DOM ([see JQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html) at bottom of page), but be careful because if you load too many into the DOM, you'll run into device-specific memory issues.

To cache a particular page, you can add the data-dom-cache="true" attribute to the page's container (for example your `index.html` page):

```
<div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true">
```

To keep all previously-visited pages in the DOM, set the domCache option on the page plugin to true in a separate JS file called AFTER you load jQuery but BEFORE you load jQuery mobile, like this:

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
```

Alternatively, you could create a HTML5 cache manifest file which will store all files you specify in the cache, whereby the app will even work when offline. There are downsides to this method, but it depends how you want your app to function. Here's the docs on the HTML5 cache manifest and how-to: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/